# Change date of VMware station

Tags: vmware

I need to change the date of my VMware system (Windows XP SP4).  I am running version 7.1.2 build-301548 of VMware which is installed on Windows 7 SP1 64 bit.

A year ago, I found some tool which was able to changed the date on the XP virtual machine to the date I wanted.

Now, I can't find that tool.  Does anyone else know of any other way of doing this?

Comment: There is no such thing as SP4 for Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest VMware tools on the VM. In this tool set, you can do the date changes that you are looking for.